# No Refusal letter for submission

Tags: visas

What happens if I don't have a visa refusal letter ? To be submitted during application process for a another country ? I had applied for asylum initially got refused reappeals to consider in human rights basis .. Refused preaction protocol appeal - refused. Submitted my voluntary return. Got a year ban to reapply . Which is likely to finish serving now.

So when I am applying for other countries in particular say Ireland ..they ask us previous visa refusals I am happy to tell the truth I don't want to hide any but I don't have those refusal letters for my appeals or even my asylum refusal letter . Would that be ok ?! Or what are the chance of getting refused becoz of no refusal letters. Or other wise is it ok to have claimed asylum and expect to further travel or that's it I can't travel
Anywhere anymore ? Does this application of my asylum will be in immigration my electronic record? Though I have a new passport . Even if they have registered my asylum in the Indian database . Will the Irish embassy be able
To view it when giving away the visa ?

Comment: Hi Mathur. In order to answer your question we need a lot more info. What is your nationality? Where were you refused a visa from? Where are you applying to? Why do you think you should include the refusal letter? Why don't you have a refusal letter? Please edit this info into the question.

Comment: I hold a Indian passport . While I was in the uk I made a stupid decision of applying for asylum which got refused . The reason to apply asylum was expecting a baby n that I could apply on human rights to stay as I was inforned. It was refused initially n aswell my later reappeals. Then I applied to return bak voluntarily. Now I wanted to pursue my research in Ireland. I do not have those asylum refusal letters Coz I thought I don't need it. Since Irish visa application asks whether I was refused any visa anywhere !! So I will have to write this asylum refusal wouldn't I ? Or should I not ?

Comment: Well i was expecting a baby and my visa had ran out and I was adviced to apply to be there at the time of birth based on human rights . They didn't acknowledge it . So I requested to return voluntarily as I realised it was a mistake. I don't have a deportation symbol in my passport though. So what do you think

Comment: Please edit all this information into the question. Click the edit link under the question.

Comment: Also you said something about 'appeals'. Please edit the details of those appeals into the question.

Comment: I had edited my question plz have a look an let me know please .

Comment: Which country did you apply for asylum in?

Comment: I had applied in the uk . Becoz I was about to have a baby in there .

Answer (score 3):

You want to apply as a visitor to the Republic of Ireland. You claimed asylum in the UK because your girlfriend was pregnant; your claim failed and you were removed to India.

> but I don't have those refusal letters for my appeals or even my
>   asylum refusal letter . Would that be ok ?

Yes, it's OK. But understand that they will ask the UK to send your paperwork, and the UK will dig it out of their archives. This could take up to two years after which your premise for visiting the ROI will most likely have expired.

> Or what are the chance of getting refused becoz of no refusal letters.

They will not refuse based upon lack of documentation from you. As explained above, they will locate the paperwork first, and then refuse on the grounds that you are not a bona fide visitor.

> Or other wise is it ok to have claimed asylum and expect to further
>   travel or that's it I can't travel Anywhere anymore ?

When somebody claims asylum it is tantamount to saying they fear persecution in their homeland and they accept the likelihood of never returning.   This is the polar opposite of what a visitor is all about. To complicate things, you took the UK government to court after you knew you had a specious claim (this was a judgement error that they will not forgive because it needlessly wastes public funds).

> Does this application of my asylum will be in immigration my
>   electronic record? Though I have a new passport .

Your passport has nothing to do with it (and why does it matter if your stated intent is to be honest?).  You may (or may not) remember when you filed your asylum claim that they took your biometrics.  When you apply to the ROI, your biometrics will be collected again and matched up.  They will then assume that you want to enter the ROI and then use the soft border to the UK and then go underground. It's a fair assumption on their part and the onus is on you to rebut it.

> Will the Irish embassy be able To view it when giving away the visa ?

Your stated intent of being honest makes it irrelevant what they can and cannot see. But as mentioned, the ROI will ask the UK to provide copies, and you can expect it to take a hellishly long time.

> Since Irish visa application asks whether I was refused any visa
>   anywhere !! So I will have to write this asylum refusal wouldn't I ?
>   Or should I not ?

You can select either option, write it down or not, declare it or not.  Biometrics made this sort of thing a lot easier for both options.

> I don't have a deportation symbol in my passport though. So what do
>   you think

They do not deport failed asylum seekers, instead they issue administrative removal orders.  You wrote that your ban is nearing expiry. The absence of a ban  doesn't mean you will have a successful application however. Your best option at this point is to visit the USA and other places with closely managed visa regimes, like Schengen.

---

I know you have other questions on the site where you use comments introduce new material and to debate the merits of your case. It's not how the site is modelled.  We are not the Upper Tribunal and we're not the Garda Síochána; questions about the merits of a given case are heavily opinion-based.  See 
https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more info.

Comment: Aye I come cross as if I am trying to deceit being underhandedness with my questions ..I AM NOT ... It's just my worry to see what things They could preview on my application . I applied in the courts before applying asylum but subsequently on my second hearing I withdrew my application and that's when I applied asylum . You say "biometrics made this sort of thing lot more easier both sides ! What do you mean by both sides ?"when you say travel

Comment: Aye Icome crossas if Iamtrying todeceit being underhandednesswith myquestions ..I AM NOT.It's just myworry to see what thingsThey couldpreview onmy application . I applied in thecourts beforeapplying asylum but subsequently on my secondhearing I withdrew myapplication and that's when I applied asylum.You say"biometrics made this sortof thing lotmore easierbothsides ! Whatdo youmean byboth sides ?"when you saytravel to closelymanaged regimesdoesn't theireland and ukform apartof Scheganterritory ?! Wouldn't theyhave mydetails ?which meansicannotgetaschenganvisa!!Will I beable toget a Schegan one

Comment: Btw I was about to get a student visa for my research not visiting visa . And the child's mam has got all the parental rights and that way I don't have any connection. Now will i be able to travel to eu ? Or will I be asked my refusals again?! If so there are chances to get refused once again .. I m gutted of the fact I took a terrible decision of applying asylum on a very very bad advice .

Comment: Tell the truth during your application and hope for the best. The application will most likely be denied, but any lies or omissions would be even more damaging. Or wait with your application until you have graduated from university and got a stable job in India. Your decision.

Comment: @o.m you say it will most likely be denied. You mean to Ireland ? Or the EU?

Comment: @Mathur, both. Ireland is in the EU, and as Gayot Fow explained there would be special concerns that you want to go to the UK. But the Schengen area would also be worried that you would overstay or claim asylum.

Comment: Right ok .. So I could never travel ? Or as mentioned get a stable job and stuff .. Would that be a fair point that I will be back .. Irrespective of the visa ? Say it a visitor or student visa ?!

Comment: @Gayot Fow Do you mean if the OP applies for a visa, it will take them two years to reach a decision? Isn't that against their published rules where they must decide a case within 90 days?

Comment: I am reading too many short forms ... What's OP now

Comment: @greatone the UK is not reaching a decision, it's the ROI. The UK is just responding to a request.

Comment: @Mathur OP means "original poster" - the person who asked the question. meaning you.

Comment: "You can select either option, write it down or not, declare it or not.". True, but doesn't not declaring it mean Mathur will be considered to have made a fraudulent application, putting her in even more trouble than she is in now?

Comment: @DJClayworth  LOL, yes, but the OP is about 8 standard deviations out already and deception would have an incremental effect of moving it to the 9th or 10th standard deviation :)

Comment: @Gayot Fow what would happen while the UK is processing the ROI's request? Would the application remain pending for 2 years? That's beyond ridiculous.

Comment: @greatone: *"For most visas, you can expect a decision 8 weeks after it was received by the Irish Visa Office, Embassy or Consulate you sent it to. ... Your application may also take longer if ...  Your supporting documentation needs to be verified ... [or] ... Because of personal circumstances, eg you have a criminal conviction"* - [ROI INIS](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Current_Processing_Times) - If the ROI feel like giving an early decision where there appears to be a history of deceit in visa & asylum applications, vexatious litigation, I imagine it is more likely to be negative.